# Brain tree recurring subscription plan with multiple currencies

Tags: payment-gateway, braintree, subscription, recurring-billing

i am using braintree payments with recurring subscription

i wanted add the subscription with multiple foreign currencies (USD,CAD,INR,GBP,..)

I am having the in app purchases also, while creating the plan in google/IOS, I am adding corresponding currency type and price for each country

can i do the same for brain tree also 
creating a one month plan -> setting the default currency type and price -> and configure to multiple currencies (for single plan) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Subscriptions can only be created in the currency belonging to the Plan from which they were created. If you create a subscription with a merchant account that is a different currency, you will receive a [validation error](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/all/ruby#code-91923).

If you want to create subscriptions in different currencies, you'll need to make sure you [create a plan](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans) for each currency and specify the corresponding merchant account ID when creating the subscription.